# How to use _set in SerializerMethod for instance?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to calculate the average rating by using SerializerMethodField().
The error in the following code is **AttributeError: 'FeedbackModel' object has no attribute 'aggregate'**

I think _set is missing but I don't know where to put it..!

```
class FeedbackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    feedback_by_user_profile_pic = serializers.ImageField(source='feedback_by.profile_pic')
    average_rating = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_average_rating(self,instance):
        return instance.aggregate(average_rating=Avg('rating'))['average_rating']

    class Meta:
        model = FeedbackModel
        fields = ['feedback_text','rating','date','feedback_by_user_profile_pic','average_rating']
```

Feedback Model

```
class FeedbackModel(models.Model):
    feedback_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    feedback_by = models.ForeignKey(UserModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business_account = models.ForeignKey(BusinessAccountModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'feedback'
```

BusinessAccountModel

```
class BusinessAccountModel(models.Model):
    business_title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    business_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'wp_business_acc'
```

BusiAccSerializer

```
class BusiAccSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BusinessAccountModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Do you need to get average rating for the user?

Comment: I need to get an average rating for a specific business_account.

Comment: What is the name of the serializer for the `BusinesssAccountModel`?

Comment: BusiAccSerializer

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the `average_rating` field in the `BusiAccSerializer`, not in the `FeedbackSerializer`.
First you have to set the `related_name` attribute in the `FeedbackModel`.

```
class FeedbackModel(models.Model):
    ...
    # here I added the `related_name` attribute
    business_account = models.ForeignKey(BusinessAccountModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="feedbacks")
```

And then in the `BusiAccSerializer`,

```
class BusiAccSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    average_rating = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)

    def get_average_rating(self, obj):
        return obj.feedbacks.aggregate(average_rating = Avg('rating'))['average_rating']

    class Meta:
        model = BusinessAccountModel
        fields = (
            'business_title', 'business_description', 'status', 'note', 'user', 'average_rating',
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you've indicated that you need an average rating for a business account, but you can not get an average rating for an account without having a concrete business account, so you need to do it in the business account serializer.

David Lu has already answered how to do it in the BusiAccSerializer, but I have something to add:
What you've trying to do is to use a serializer method field to add some aggregated data to the output. This way of solving your problem has a major drawback: when you will try to serialize a list of BusinessAccountModels, the serializer will do a separate database call for each business account and it could be slow. You better need to specify an annotated queryset in your view like this:

```
BusinessAccountModel.objects.all().annotate(average_rating=Avg('feedbacks__rating'))
```

Then you will be able to use the result of calculation as a regular field in your serializer:

```
class BusiAccSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    average_rating = serializers.FloatField(read_only=True)
```

This way there will be no additional database queries done by the serializer.